# How to limit MAX an MIN length of a string?

Tags: sed, awk, perl

"nothing" means no OUTPUT.

**Q:** how can I limit the MIN and MAX length of a piped **STRING**? (MIN: x>=3 chars, MAX: x<=32 chars)

INPUT:

```
echo 12 | MAGIC
```

OUTPUT:

```
nothing
```

---

INPUT:

```
echo 123 | MAGIC
```

OUTPUT:

```
123
```

---

INPUT:

```
echo 123456789012345678901234567890123 | MAGIC
```

OUTPUT:

```
nothing
```

---

INPUT:

```
echo 12345678901234567890123456789012 | MAGIC
```

OUTPUT:

```
12345678901234567890123456789012
```

Comment: E.g  `str="123"; (( ${#str} >= 3 && ${#str} <= 32 )) && echo "VALID length"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
echo 123 | awk 'length >= 3 && length <= 32'
```

If you pipe multiple lines to it, it will print lines with between 3 and 32 characters.

Answer (score 2):

While [David's `awk` one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86567/22565) is the most obvious one, to add to the list:

```
grep -xE '.{3,32}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -nle 'print if length() > 2 and length() < 33'
```

Test1:

```
echo "12345678901234567890123456789012" | \
perl -nle 'print if length() > 2 and length() < 33'
```

Output:

```
12345678901234567890123456789012
```

Test2:

```
echo "123456789012345678901234567890123" | \
perl -nle 'print if length() > 2 and length() < 33'
```

Output:

```
<Nothing>
```